# Continuously Showing "Turn on Bluetooth to allow app to connect to accessories" alert message in background in ios

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am using iBeacon Technology in my application. I'm checking in the app whether the bluetooth is enabled or disable by the user  and for that i have written code below.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
 {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  _bluetoothManager =  [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:nil];
}

  // bluetooth manager state change
  - (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
 {
 NSString *stateString = nil;
 switch(central.state)
 {
    case CBCentralManagerStateResetting: stateString = @"The connection with the system service was momentarily lost, update imminent."; break;
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported: stateString = @"The platform doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy."; break;
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized: stateString = @"The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy."; break;
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff: stateString = @"Bluetooth is currently powered off."; break;
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn: stateString = @"Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use."; break;
    default: stateString = @"State unknown, update imminent."; break;
  }
 }
```

[image]

**Problem** : This above alert Message prompts very oftenly in background or when the other app is open even if i have kill the application. I want to show this default alert message but only when the user opens the app.

Can anyone provide me a solution?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't accessing Bluetooth somewhere else?  ViewDidLoad should only fire when a view controller is loaded. What background modes (if any) have you set for your app?

Comment: Yes I'm only using Bluetooth to check whether it is enable or disable. I have enable. And In capabilities, Only Remote notification is enabled. I think, I'm facing this issue from ios 8.

Comment: You should try removing the options for the showPowerAlertKey and if that doesn't help use a notification observer to release your central manager when your app enters the background.

Comment: At first, i have tried it without this showPowerAlertKey option but that also  didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

```
self.bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                                             queue:nil
                                                           options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: @NO}];
```

This maybe works to hide the system pop up.

Comment: I want to show the alert so that the user can easily navigate to bluetooth setting option.

Comment: Maybe no way navigate user to bluetooth settings, you can alert user by text, or a special UI, when delegate callback `central.state` is  `case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff`

Comment: There you go `self.bluetoothManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: false])`